# Get key from select value on PHP array with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm not even sure if this is possible as I haven't been able to find anything that could help me figure out this, so I thought I'd ask.

I have a wordpress site with a user registration plugin that has a select dropdown state field with an array:

```
$array = array(
 'AL' => 'Alabama',
 'AK' => 'Alaska',
 'AZ' => 'Arizona',
 'AR' => 'Arkansas');
```

I'm trying to sync this field with woocommerce's billing_state field, which from what I can tell uses the abbreviations instead of the full name (Al, instead of Alabama).

I figured I would use the dropdown field to get the selected state and pass it along to the billing_state field by using the value attribute, but this passes along the full name, is there a way to retrieve the key instead and pass it on to the value of the input field?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Drop down keys using jQuery [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) API.

e.g. if your drop down id is `states`:

```
var state = $("#state").val();
```

Comment: That's what I have but I'm still getting the full name rather than the key, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Paste the drop down HTML source here.\

Comment: `<select name="state_dropdown" id="state_dropdown" data-placeholder="Please Select"><option value="Alabama">Alabama</option><option value="Alaska">Alaska</option><option value="Arizona">Arizona</option></select>`

Ok so I clearly see the problem, even though the dropdown is being populated through the php array, the values are the full state name. I guess I have to rephrase my original question. Is there a way to include the key somewhere in the select options?

Comment: There we go, the option values are state names, they should be state codes.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll have to take a look at the code in the registration plugin, figure out where the options are added from the built-in arrays and change it.

Answer (score 0):

If your select box is like this

```
<select class='states' name='states'>
    <option value='AL'>Alabama</option>
    <option value='AK'>Alaska</option>
    <option value='AZ'>Arizona</option>
    <option value='AR'>Arkansas</option>
</select>
```

there are many ways you could get the selected value i'm listing only a few

```
1. $("select.states").val();
2. $("select.states option:selected").val();
```

I'm assuming you might need the updated value on change so, something like this

```
$("select.states").on('change',function(){
    var state_abbreviations = $(this).val();
});
```

The above detects the user change and passes the data each time for you to update your required fields.

Hope this is helpful.

Edit : If your values in the options are interchanged, then you would need to use something like

```
$("select.states").on('change',function(){
        var state_abbreviations = $(this).text();
});
```